# Unable to send SMS on Android

Tags: android

I written following code to send sms.

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber)
{        
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                dialog.setMessage("SMS is Successfully Sent for Contact Request ");
                dialog.setTitle("ALERT:SMS Sent");

                dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    return;

                }
                });
                dialog.show();
                break;


            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
          }
         return;
     }
  }, new IntentFilter(SENT));


registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;                        
        }
    }
  }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
  sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messageToSend, sentPI, deliveredPI);      
}
```

The code is running successfully in Emulator but not in phone.
It shows the following error

```
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",);
```

I have given the required permissions and have SIM(with enough balance)  in the phone as well.

Comment: Try to run this app on another android phone.Code looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Are you using the correct `SmsManager`, the one from the `gsm` package is deprecated? Could you show us the permissions you are using? Do you have coverage on your phone?

Comment: yeah I am using smsmanager of telephony package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this piece of code for sending message

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    Log.d("phoneNumber",phoneNumber);
    Log.d("MEssage",message);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(CONTEXT, 0,
        new Intent(CONTEXT,Object.class), 0);                
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
}
```